# correct shebang for virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, shebang, python-packaging

I have Project shell_script and structure tree of virtualenv is shell_script/ENV/bin/python3
What should look like shebang to this dir tree?

This is not working

```
#!/ENV/bin/env python3.6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have your virtualenv activated, you can use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.x
```

and that will find the proper executable you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
#!/path/to/ENV/bin/python3
```

**However**, it's the installer which writes out the shebang for a script.  You should not write it out manually.  **Whatever shebang you write manually in the source code will just get rewritten by the installer, when the package is installed.**

Whichever Python executable was used by the installer will be hardcoded into the shebang, so if you `pip install` from within the virtualenv then the virtualev's path to Python executable will be used. If you `pip install` with system Python then the system executable will be used.